# Extensive logging for each rest call without affecting performance

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka

In our application we do lot of calculation on rest call and then return the result. For analytics purpose we want to log complete calculation logic (in a such way that we can know how and why we gave certain result). We are thinking of sending each log statement to kafka and then have elastic search consumer to capture the logs for given request. Since we will be doing lot of logging for each request what can we do so that performance is not affected because of logs? Also is the any library which can help us?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use MQ like Kafka but I suggest you use single partition because multi-partition does not guarantee order.
You can launch another service to do the collecting work, your programm just send log to Kafka with your request id, and the service consume Kafka data and merge your log by request id.

Comment: yeah that the idea but is it a good idea to have the application machines direclty call kafka ? The machines get close to a 100k hits /min. I don't want anything to impact the application machines.